# How do I rollback a VersionedItem to a previous version with the CoreService?

Tags: core-service, content-manager, powershell

As part of a data-migration script, I need to be able to rollback a Component to a previous (known) version. How do I do that using the Coreservice (sites 9.0)?

Bonus points for Powershell syntax ....

=> "Rollback component tcm:1-123" to version 8"

Answer (score 4):

In powershell:

```
Import-Module "Tridion-CoreService"

# rollback
$client = Get-TridionCoreServiceClient
$client.Rollback("tcm:1-123-v8", $false, "rolling back", $null)
$client.Close()
"Done"
```

Answer (score 3):

The Core Service has a "Rollback" method:

```
VersionedItemData Rollback(
    TcmUri id,
    bool deleteVersions,
    string comment,
    ReadOptions readBackOptions
)
```

**id** - The identifier of the VersionedItemData to rollback. The identifier must be a TCM URI including the version to rollback to.

**deleteVersions** - Specifies whether to delete all versions after the given version or to create a new version which is a copy of the given version.

**comment** - Comment for the specified version. Usually used to list references to items that no longer exists. Maybe null or "".

**readBackOptions** - Specifies how the VersionedItemData is read back after rolling back. If the parameter is null, the object is not read back.